# How to understand compiler behavior difference with << operator and stringstream between Visual Studio 2010 and VS 2013

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, googletest

We are migrating a solution from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013. One of the projects in the solution uses GTest for unit testing.

When I first built my test project under VS 2013, the compiler complained with:

> Error 1   error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a
>   left-hand operand of type 'std::ostream' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

It locates the error on `gtest-internal.h`:

```
// To allow STL containers (and other types that has a << operator
// defined in the global namespace) to be used in Google Test assertions,
// testing::Message must access the custom << operator from the global
// namespace.  Hence this helper function.
//
// Note: Jeffrey Yasskin suggested an alternative fix by "using
// ::operator<<;" in the definition of Message's operator<<.  That fix
// doesn't require a helper function, but unfortunately doesn't
// compile with MSVC.
template <typename T>
inline void GTestStreamToHelper(std::ostream* os, const T& val) {
  *os << val;
}
```

I tracked down the problem to this section of code:

```
std::stringstream tag;
tag << "tag" << i;
ASSERT_NO_THROW(map.at(tag.str())) << "found tag: " << tag;
```

So while this compiled fine in VS2010, it only works if I change it to:

```
std::stringstream tag;
tag << "tag" << i;
ASSERT_NO_THROW(map.at(tag.str())) << "found tag: " << tag.str();
```

Given my weak brain for understanding these c++ subtleties, I would really appreciate an explanation about the change in behavior and what is wrong with the first variation that worked in VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work change the code to this. Hope it helps.

```
#include <ostream>
template <typename T>
inline void GTestStreamToHelper(std::ostream* os, const T& val) {
  *os << val;
```

}

Comment: I will see if this helps.  It would be strange to need to change one of the GoogleTest header files, but if it fixes the problem, that would be great!

Comment: I did try as you suggested, but the problem really turned out to be a spot in my code where it was invoking the GTEST macro with the wrong object type.  Apparently VS 2010 did some kind of automatic conversion (or navigation to correct operator method) that couldn't be done VS 2013.  (See the edits I made to my question.)

Comment: @SamGoldberg Well I'm glad that you understood how to fix it.